# Using ModelBuilder for adding and calculating field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, fields-attributes

How can I add a field, calculate the area in it then export the maps as an excel sheet using the ModelBuilder for all the data stored in the geodatabase file?

Note, the picture was my try to do the task.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder from ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: You need to connect "Feature Class" to "Add Field" as the input feature class.  Then make sure that your initial "Workspace or Feature Dataset" has a valid default value.  Then see if the model will validate.  You should also include the "Name" variable as part of the output Excel document in the "Table to Excel" tool (eg, as `C:/some/folder/location/%Name%.xls`) to make sure that you're not overwriting the same Excel document for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your Feature Class to Add value. Assuming you have the parameters set up correctly in the model you've built that should do the trick.